# How can I make table cell span multiple lines in MultiMarkdown?

Tags: perl, markup

I'm using [Text::MultiMarkdown](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::MultiMarkdown) to print from Perl to HTML.

I would like to create a table where some of the cells contain a few strings, each in a separate line within the cell (see "four five six" in the picture below).[image: sample table]

Can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Text::MultiMarkdown passes some HTML straight through so you can use `<br>` tags:

```
print Text::MultiMarkdown::markdown(q{
Header 1 | Header 2
-------- | ---------------------------
One line | First line<br />Second line
});
```

It produces a table body like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>One line</td>
    <td>First line<br />Second line</td>
</tr>
```

Which seems to be what you're looking for.